# Why does php artisan create migration class with empty up method?

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I am currently learning from this video

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/7

about database migrations in laravel.
I typed in console :

php artisan make:migration create_projects_table

just like the teacher in the video and somehow I get an empty method definition in the migrations folder.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProjectsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        //should contain Schema::create but it is empty
    }


    public function down()
    {

    }
}
```

What did I do wrong? I followed all those instructions in the video.

Comment: Why should it creates something? how laravel knows what you wanna do with the migration? this is the correct behaviour.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I have used this command in laravel 5.5 and it works, what's your laravel version ?

Comment: @kerbholz I was sure it was the correct behaviour. Atleast in laravel 5.2

Comment: @kerbholz are you sure you do not have to use `--create` or `--table` parameters to the command to let laravel write code for you?

Comment: I just tested this and if I use `php artisan make:migration create_projects_table` all the basic code gets created. If I use `php artisan make:migration test_my_table` _NO_ basic code gets created. Maybe remove your migration and generate a new one.

Comment: My laravel version is   5.4.36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can specify the table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#generating-migrations):

> php artisan make:migration create_projects_table --create=projects

**edit**: It should indeed work without adding the argument: 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/854e6d1d001f5e9a6d1376d2284eaa99b0c1e443/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateMakeCommand.php#L88

```
        // Next, we will attempt to guess the table name if this the migration has
        // "create" in the name. This will allow us to provide a convenient way
        // of creating migrations that create new tables for the application.
        if (! $table) {
            [$table, $create] = TableGuesser::guess($name);
        }
```

[The tableGuesser class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/TableGuesser.php)

Here you can see that your tables name should match `(\w+)` pattern

Comment: Normally command should work without adding --create=projects

Comment: @SagarGautam Hmm well maybe he should get the debugger to find out why then for his specific case

Comment: I have created a migration some hours before without mentioning --create=table_name that worked perfectly ;)

Comment: Yep, It works right now. Thanks. Maybe the video is a little bit old.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command on root folder

```
php artisan make:migration create_projects_table --create=projects //create only Migration file

php artisan make:model Project -m //Create Migration, Model file

php artisan make:model Project -mcr //For Create Migration,Model,Controller file
```

Comment: Yes, apparently the teacher from the video uses different version of laravel. If you read the documentation you will see the same syntax as yours.

Comment: yes in your question `--create=projects` is missing and `php artisan make:migration create_projects_table` it'll create only migration file.